# Understanding @input and @output in Angular2

Tags: angular

For the example at url:

http://ngcourse.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html

I am unable to understand how the following two lines function with respect to @Output

```
//in app.component.ts
    (countChange)="number2=$event"
    (countChange)="onCountChanged($event)


//counter.component.ts
@Output() countChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

can someone help connect the dots here.

Answer (score 1):

```ts
this.countChange.emit('foo');
```

in `counter.component.ts` dispatches an event

(a bit similar to a click or other DOM event, but only handled in Angular internally)

```ts
(countChange)="onCountChanged($event)
```

registers a listener for this `countChange` event.
It might be a bit confusing because Angular uses the same binding syntax for `@Output()` as for DOM events.

When `this.countChange.emit('foo');` is executed the registered event handler is called and `'foo'` is passed (for the `$event` argument).

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms,

To trigger `custom events`, `EventEmitter` is used (generally from `childcmp` to `parentcmp`). `@Output` is a way to declare custom event name (type of `EventEmitter`).

In your case it is (from ***counter.component.ts***),

```
@Output() countChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

says `countChange` is a custom event (type of `EventEmitter`). `EventEmitter` has methods like **emit()**, **next()** which can emit values. So here it says `countChange` can emit number value. eg.

```
count=5;
buttonClick(){
    this.countChange.emit(this.count); // will emit 5 value 
}
```

Note whenever `EventEmitter` (here `countChange`) emits any (`number`) value, custom event(generally used in `parentcmp`) will be triggered by its own.

In your case it is (from ***app.component.ts***),

```
(countChange)="number2=$event"  //number2=5; //countChange is a custom event
```

automatically `this.count`'s ***5*** value will be received through ***$event*** and so it will be assigned to ***number2***. which is also applicable for below code.

```
(countChange)="onCountChanged($event)  //countChange is a custom event
```

somewhere written in component.

```
onCountChanged(value)
 {
      console.log(value); // =5;
 }
```

Comment: I think anyone who's walked through a tutorial, understands what the effect of using `@Output` is within the context of using `EventEmitter<T>`. **The question** that we're all asking, if I may, is: *Does `@Output` create new & custom event-types? Or does it depend on what the context is? What if I assign `@Output notAnEvent = [ 1, 2, 3 ]`? How in the world does Angular know what the event's name/type is, unless we assume to have some TypeScript magic? What makes `@Output` and output? And finally, what's the difference b/w this approach & using `@Input` to pass in a callback (as in React)?*

Answer (score 1):

I actually think Angular's own examples on how `@Input` and `@Output` work are pretty poor.

Here is a simple StackBlitz example, which shows how it's done:
https://angular-ivy-yqycev.stackblitz.io

It looks like this:

[image]

When you type in characters in the "transmitter" textbox, it'll send your string as an `@Output`... and the "receiver" will receive it via as an `@Input`, and show it in it's own textbox.

The key thing is that the "Transmitter" component will use an `@Output`...

*transmitter.component.html:*

```
<div>
  <h3>Transmitter</h3>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" />
</div>
```

*transmitter.component.ts:*

```
  @Output() emitter = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onChange(event:any) {
    this.emitter.emit(this.value);
  }
```

And the "Receiver" component will use an `@Input()`...

*receiver.component.html:*

```
<div>
  <h3>Receiver</h3>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" />
</div>
```

*receiver.component.ts:*

```
  @Input() inputValue = "";
```

And, you can tie them together using this:

*app.component.html:*

```
  <app-transmitter (emitter)="onEmitter($event)"></app-transmitter>
  <app-receiver [inputValue]="currentValue"></app-receiver>
```

*app.component.ts:*

```
export class AppComponent  {

  currentValue = '';

  onEmitter(event:any) {
      console.log('Received: ' + event);
      this.currentValue = event;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !